# Unable to convert bitmap image into byte[]

Tags: android, arrays, image, bitmap

I want convert my captured image into byte[]. When I capture image using camera it gets captured and preview is also shown and images saves on my external storage as well successfully.But when I try to convert my preview image it doesn't stores anything in the byte array.
Following is my method which is called when I press preview image button on my phone.

```
public static void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        static ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),options);
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert image to string & byte array,  use following short of code.

---

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
yourbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
//this will convert image to byte[] 
byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray(); 
// this will convert byte[] to string
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below working code. This includes quality adjustment also

```
/**
 * @param bitmap
 * @param quality 1 ~ 100
 * @return
 */
public static byte[] compressBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality)
{
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, baos);

        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        PrintLog.print(TAG, e.toString(), e);
    }

    return null;
}
```